# Defining a function that counts 2 letters and divides that by total length of the word

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a code that counts how many G's and C's there are in a "strand of DNA" and calculate the percentage of the G's + C's in that strand, e.g.

```
gcContent('CGGTCCAATAGATTCGAA')
44.4444444444
```

There are 18 letters in that string and 8 G's + C's together.

I am struggling so far to even count the letter of G's in a strand in my code, this is what I have so far:

```
def gcContent(dnaMolecule):
    count = 0
    for g in dnaMolecule:
        dnaMolecule.count('g')
        count += 1
    return count
```

and when I type it into the interactive python shell the result is this:

```
In [1]: gcContent('a')
Out[1]: 1.0
```

It's not counting the amount of G's so far and it says one no matter what if I type in 1 character inside the brackets after `gcContent`.

Comment: You don't need a loop for this, `dnaMolecule.count('G')` is enough

Comment: Use count or a loop but not both, assign the result of count, and the most important `'g' != 'G'`.

Comment: You're _calling_ `dnaMolecule.count('g')`, but you're not doing anything with the _result_.  Also, you probably want `.count('G')`, not `.count('g')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `count` method that every string has.

```
def gcContent(dnaMolecule):
    dnaMolecule = dnaMolecule.lower()
    count = dnaMolecule.count('g') + dnaMolecule.count('c')
    return count / len(dnaMolecule)
```

For Python 2.x and getting a value between 0 - 100 instead of 0 - 1:

```
def gcContent(dnaMolecule):
    dnaMolecule = dnaMolecule.lower()
    count = dnaMolecule.count('g') + dnaMolecule.count('c')
    return 100.0 * count / len(dnaMolecule)
```

Comment: Nice and simple answer (upvote from me); my only comment is that in Python 2, you would need to return `count / float(len(dnaMolecule))` because of integer division issues in Python 2. Otherwise, good answer.

Comment: what if the input  is `CGGGggg`

Comment: @AlexL. Agreed. The OP did specify python-3.x though.

Comment: @TammoHeeren Right. I forgot to look at the tags.

Comment: @PavneetSingh That will not be a problem, because Tammo used `dnaMolecule.lower()`, which would turn `CGGGggg` into `cgggggg`, and then the count function would work as wanted.

Comment: @PavneetSingh If the distinction matters you could simply remove the `.lower()`, but I don't think that DNA discriminates between them.

Comment: @PavneetSingh I agree, case doesn't matter in DNA, but the standard is that they should all be written in capitals.

Comment: Additionally, I would suggest that you create a new variable and assign `dnaMolecule.lower()` to it; that way, you don't have to call `.lower()` twice.

Comment: @AlexL. yeah my indication was in other direction ,  Tammo , just curious , i not really aware with DNA patterns

Comment: @AlexL. Agreed with calling `.lower()` twice. Fixed the code.

Comment: The code works but was just wondering the 'dnaMolecule.lower()' just makes it so that if the string had lower case letters it will be counted a well right?

Comment: @Langfao Yes. `.lower()` just converts the entire string to lowercase.

Comment: @Tammo Heeren thanks, I am also trying to convert the answer into a percentage but when I do `return count * 100 / len(dnaMolecule)` the answer still remains a decimal?

Comment: @Langfao You are likely using python 2.x. Change `100` into `100.0` and you should get floats.

Comment: @TammoHeeren I am using python 3.5.1 isn't that python 3.x? Also changing 100 to 100.0 didn't make a difference.

Comment: I just ran the first code with the following sequence `gcContent('CGGTCCAATAGATTCGAA')` and got a result of `0.4444...` (using python 3.5)

Comment: @TammoHeeren now I'm running the code both ways and it works, as well changing the position of where the 100 is I am very confused, anyways thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you can make use of [Biopython](http://biopython.org/wiki/Documentation), there is already a predefined function [`GC`](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.SeqUtils-module.html) which calculates the GC content of a given sequence:

```
from Bio.SeqUtils import GC

print(GC('CGGTCCAATAGATTCGAA'))
```

That gives the desired output:

```
44.44444444444444
```

Depending on what additional things you want to do with your sequence, I highly recommend to use the predefined functions rather than writing your own ones.

EDIT:

As this is discussed below @TammoHeeren's answer, `GC` also takes care of the lower/upper case issue:

```
print(GC('CGGGggg'))
```

gives

```
100.0
```

Comment: Nice answer. I did not know that someone actually made a module for this. Interesting!